# cobra-cli pass all arguments and flags to an executable

Tags: go, go-cobra

I have a cobra CLI for my own stuff. Now I want to add commonly used executables *e.g.* `kubectl`, `calicoctl` as subcommands which will consume all arguments and flags like

```
mywrapper kubectl get all --all-namespaces
mywrapper kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --port=80
```

Reproduce cobra project

```
mkdir mywrapper; cd mywrapper; go mod init mywrapper; cobra-cli init .
```

And add a subcommand *e.g.* `kubectl`

```
cobra-cli add kubectl
```

Then populate `./cmd/kubectl.go` with

```
package cmd

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

var kubectlCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "kubectl",
    Short: "run kubectl",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("kubectl %v", strings.Join(args, " "))).Output()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(out))
    },
}

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(kubectlCmd)
}
```

I can now run `kubectl` command *e.g.* `go run . kubectl get pods`. But it fails when flags are added *e.g.* `go run . kubectl get pods --selector app=nginx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your flags after the `--`. A double dash (--) is used to signify the end of command options. In our case it is required to distinguish between the flags passed to `go` and those that aren't. Everything after the double dash wont be considered to be `go`'s flags.

I tried with gcloud:

```
package cmd

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

var gcloudCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "gcloud",
    Short: "run gcloud",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        out, err := exec.Command("gcloud", args...).Output()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(out))
    },
}

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(gcloudCmd)
}
```

Then tried:

```
$ go run . gcloud compute regions list -- --filter="id<1250"

NAME          CPUS  DISKS_GB  ADDRESSES  RESERVED_ADDRESSES  STATUS  TURNDOWN_DATE
asia-east1    0/24  0/4096    0/8        0/8                 UP
europe-west1  0/24  0/4096    0/8        0/8                 UP
us-central1   0/24  0/4096    0/8        0/8                 UP
us-east1      0/24  0/4096    0/8        0/8                 UP
us-west1      0/24  0/4096    0/8        0/8                 UP
```

Adding more flags:

```
$ go run . gcloud compute regions list -- --filter="id<1250" --format="table(name,id)"

NAME          ID
asia-east1    1220
europe-west1  1100
us-central1   1000
us-east1      1230
us-west1      1210
```

Comment: should work for most cases. though for example, `kubectl exec podname -- -it -- bash` doesn't seem to work properly